# React Native xcode build failure

Tags: xcode, react-native

Getting back to an old react-native project that used to build ok and am now seeing build errors.

When running the RN build command from the CLI I see the following error printed out multiple times

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myperks-gdtrvukhkrhlaydznulsqeffucrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-money/react_native_money.modulemap' not found
```

However, when trying to run the build via xcode I see this error

```
const unsigned char myperksVersionString[] __attribute__ ((used)) = "@(#)PROGRAM:myperks  PROJECT:myperks-4" "\n";
 const double myperksVersionNumber __attribute__ ((used)) = (double)4.;
```

xcode highlightsa this section

```
myperksVersionString[]
```

I have tried updating RN, I have cleaned the build folders and cache, uninstalled and reinstalled Pods